# linux command to copy contents of folder to root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I am using ubuntu I want to copy folder contents into another folder . I used below command

```
cp -R /home/user/public_html/domain.com /home/user/public_html/
```

But I get source and destinations are same error.

Comment: Is `/home/buy` a link to `/home/user` or `/home/buy/public_htm` a link to `/home/user/public_html`?  If so, the file is already there.

Comment: Hi , I am sorry typo...both are user...and yea folder already exists..I wanted to copy contents inside the folder.

Comment: I guess you want that: `cp -R /home/user/public_html/domain.com/* /home/user/public_html/` .. And for hidden file additionally `cp -R /home/user/public_html/domain.com/.* /home/user/public_html/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `tar` (because it block copies). Something like

```
cd /home/user/public_html/domain.com
tar cf - * | (cd .. ; tar xvf -)
```

or (using your `cp`) like

```
cd /home/user/public_html/domain.com
cp -R * ../
```